# iOS - "unrecognised selector sent to instance" error, when name label

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am sending some object, when pressing cell in my table to the other view, which have to show detail of that cell.

And when I try to change the label (on the second view) text, I get:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell nameOfItem]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8e7ab5ed40'

My object:

```
@interface Item : NSObject

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString * nameOfItem;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString * descriptionOfItem;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString * categoryOfItem;

-(instancetype)initItem:(NSString *)name category:(NSString *)category description:(NSString *)description;
-(NSComparisonResult)compare:(Item *)otherItem;

@end
```

My cell:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSMutableArray* sortedItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[ItemsTable sortItems:self.itemsTable.items]];
    self.itemsTable.items = sortedItems;


    listOfItems = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.itemsTable.items];
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    NSString *sectionTitle = [[self.itemsTable categoriesOfItemsTable] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    NSInteger index = [indexPath row];


    cell.textLabel.text = ((Item *)[[self.itemsTable listOfItemsInCategory:sectionTitle] objectAtIndex:index]).nameOfItem;


    return cell;

}
```

My row selecting:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *category = [[self.itemsTable categoriesOfItemsTable] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];//get category of selected item
    Item *testItem = [[self.itemsTable listOfItemsInCategory:category] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"IntoInfoPage" sender:testItem];
}
```

My prepare for segue:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    ...

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"IntoInfoPage"]){
        if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[InfoViewController class]]){
            InfoViewController *fivc = (InfoViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
            fivc.gotchaItem = sender;
        }
    }
}
```

and my second view:

```
@interface InfoViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameOfFullInfoItem;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *categoryOfFullInfoItem;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *descriptionOfFullInfoItem;

@end

@implementation InfoViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (self.gotchaItem)
    {
        self.nameOfFullInfoItem.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name: %@",self.gotchaItem.nameOfItem];
        self.categoryOfFullInfoItem.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Category: %@",self.gotchaItem.categoryOfItem];
        self.descriptionOfFullInfoItem.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.gotchaItem.descriptionOfItem];
    }

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Exception appears at line, that is in my second view:

```
#import "InfoViewController.h"

@interface InfoViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameOfFullInfoItem; //Here!
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *categoryOfFullInfoItem;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *descriptionOfFullInfoItem;

@end
```

Comment: what is self.gotchaItem?

Comment: @Mr.T , in header of second view

`//
//  InfoViewController.h
//  ItemsMarket
//
//  Created by Maxim on 12/18/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Maxim. All rights reserved.
//

#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "Item.h"

@interface InfoViewController : TableViewController

@property (strong,nonatomic) Item* gotchaItem;
@end`

Comment: @Mr.T it is mine object that i send to my second view

Comment: Your question is missing the most important piece of info. Which line of code is causing the exception?

Comment: @rmaddy Sorry, added (:

Comment: No, the exception is not happening at that line. The crash will happen inside one of your methods.

Comment: @rmaddy
But it does...

Comment: The exception you originally posted in your question states it is on a call to `nameOfItem`. Besides, an app doesn't crash on a property declaration.

Comment: @rmaddy
And it disappointing me. Why it crashes there, when i'm trying to change labeltext?

Comment: Youre sure that self.gotchaItem.nameOfItem isnt nil ?

Comment: When it crashes, type `bt` in the debug console and paste the stack trace into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that you are calling `nameOfItem` method on a `UITableViewCell`. That alone would be enough, but you also have the stack trace, it shouldn't be difficult to track it down.

In your attached code, this is very suspicious:

```
cell.textLabel.text = ((Item *)[[self.itemsTable listOfItemsInCategory:sectionTitle] objectAtIndex:index]).nameOfItem;
```

Set a breakpoint on that line and make sure that it's a `Item` and not a `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: I've checked. It's a Item and it is not a UITableview, it is of mine main view controller.

And my app crashes on line(property of mine second view): 
'@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameOfFullInfoItem;'

Answer (score 0):

Your app is being crashed in following line

```
 self.nameOfFullInfoItem.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name: %@",self.gotchaItem.nameOfItem];
```

Here self.gotchaItem appears to be a UITableViewCell. Thats why you can't call nameOfItem from this object. Make sure that you are sending the correct item object and self.gotchaItem should be an object of Item class.

Comment: why -1? You should left a comment about the matter.

Comment: 1) You completely changed your answer since the down vote. 2) Even the new answer is wrong. If `self.gotchItem` is actually a `UITableViewCell`, using a cast won't solve the issue. It will still crash. 3) How do you know that is the line that crashes? The OP still hasn't told us where it actually crashes.

Comment: Did you read the error message? It says "[UITableViewCell nameOfItem]: unrecognized selector sent to.." So, with my little knowledge I got that it is crashing in the line accessing nameOfItem. And I found that in two different type of places. One in list viewcontroller where OP gets the item from self.itemsTable. OP said in a comment that it is crasing on infoviewcontroller, not in the first. So, please read every comment before down voting.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that your answer is wrong. Simply adding a cast will not fix the crash.

Comment: Did you read this? "I am sending some object, when pressing cell in my table to the other view, which have to show detail of that cell.
And when I try to change the label (on the second view) text, I get:"

Don't you think that OP has said clearly where the crashing is occuring?


And in my answer, read the last line "And make sure that you are sending the correct item object."

So, Please stop arguing, and if you really can help the OP, give an answer without wasting your time.

Comment: You wrote in your answer: *"Try casting self.gotchaItem to Items before calling nameOfItem"*. That won't work. That is why your answer is wrong. Remove that line if you don't want your answer to be wrong.

Comment: In this line self.gotchaItem appears to be UITableViewCell whereas OP expects it to be Item. Thats why I asked to check the object type carefully. Though, In the question, OP clearly said the crash is occuring in next page, you didn't get that that. You asked me that "how you know that crashes on that line?" Hey, from my little knowledge, I got that. If you don't understand this, please wait.


I will be grateful to you if you stop arguing on my answer. Lets the OP to decide whether the answer is right or wrong. Thanks for your helping comment.

Comment: Please read my previous comment again. All of the other stuff is irrelevant to the discussion. The cause of the down vote is only due to what I wrote in my previous comment.

Comment: Edited, hope you are happy now.

Answer (score 0):

At first I would agree with the other answers,  but you are saying that your object is an Item,  so it leads me to think of this answer:

Have you checked that this outlet `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameOfFullInfoItem;` is properly connected to the UILabel?  Go into your interface builder and verify that only this label is connected to this outlet and nothing else.